# Invoking local lambda function by an MQTT event inside greengrass core

Tags: amazon-web-services, lambda, mqtt, aws-iot

Am working on a simple application where need to collect temperature from an sensor and publishing to an MQTT topic and trying to subscribe in another lambda function, where it need to decide on passing message to another IOT device. Following are my questions?

1. Is it a correct way to subscribe to a MQTT topic inside a Lambda function?
2. Once deployed inside greengrass core will the lambda function be invoked?
3. Will MQTT events invoke the lambda function deployed inside greengrass core if so, samples will be useful.

This whole stuff confusing a lot.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You can deploy Lambda function to Greengrass core. The Greengrass core also maintains a subscription table so that it can invoke local Lambda functions when messages are published to subscribed topics. This example might help: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/greengrass/latest/developerguide/gg-storyline.html.

Answer (score 1):

1. You don't subscribe to the lambda, you do it from the group subscriptions (lambda_source-> lambda_target)  You will also need to set-up a filter for the topic.
2. Yes, it will, you need to make sure the `receiving/subscribing` lambda handler function is defined and setup properly.  Its what will get invoked when the MQTT msg is received.  `(LambdaFilename.function_handler)`

   def function_handler(event, context):
       logger.info("Welp We got stuff")
       return